# Pragmatic Test for Total Unimodularity

Tags: linear-algebra

I want perform a simple check for total unimodularity.

**Question:**
what, if anything, can be concluded from the fact, that $$det(A)=1,\ a_{ij}\in\{-1,0,+1\}\ \wedge\ a_{ij}^{-1}\in\{-1,0,+1\}$$ 
where $a_{ij}^{-1}$ denotes the entries of $A^{-1}$?

Comment: It might be easier to try a brute force approach first to see if there are any counterexamples of size 3 or 4. We can list all ternary matrices $A$ of size n x n and then keep the ones that have determinant 1 and for whom $A^{-1}$ contains valid entries. The matrices that pass the filter can be checked for totally unimodularity using http://www.utdallas.edu/~klaus/TUtest. There are 43 million ternary matrices of size 4 x 4 so if each 4x4 matrix takes a millisecond then the entire procedure would take 12 hours. At the end you would either have a counterexample or a strong case for truth of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any counterexamples to total unimodularity for $n=3$
since when $\det A=1$  the entries of $A^{-1}$ are up to sign the
$2\times 2$ minors of $A$. On the other hand, for $n=4$ let
  $$ A=\left[ \begin{array}{rrrr} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
       0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]. $$
Then $A$ satisfies the conditions of the problem but is not totally
unimodular. In general, the conditions of the problem are just saying
that the $1\times 1$ and $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minors are $0,\pm 1$,
while the the $n\times n$ minor (i.e., $\det A$) is 1.